# WordPress: Redirect to page after 3 seconds

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Trying to redirect people going to one of my Thank You pages after visiting it for 3 seconds. Thought I could do the following in a page template designed just for this specific page:

```
get_header( "refresh:3;url=some-url-goes-here");
```

but it's not redirecting. What will make it work? Something in functions.php or .htaccess instead?

Comment: use javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage

Answer (score 0):

`get_header` has a completely different purpose.
Try using standard php `header` method: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php